# What are the typical tools used to get a Rails application from development to production?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, application-lifecycle

As an experienced .NET developer, I am interested in learning the Ruby on Rails development process. I have experience with ASP.NET WebForms and MVC, and I have used PHP as well. I have gone through some basic RoR tutorials and was able to get them working.

This question deals more specifically with the tools and development process for this type of development since it is different from what I'm used to. What are the typical tools (development, testing, deployment) used to manage the development lifecycle and get a website into production besides Rake? Is there anything I need to change about my fundamental thought process versus developing for .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For development, I personally **love** [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), but I've heard [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) is fantastic.

---

For testing, I would look into [Rspec](http://rspec.info/) & [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/).

---

For deployment, [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki), hands down.

---

Also, an afterthought, [Passenger 3 + Apache](http://www.modrails.com/) is *really, really nice* (and simple!).

(for both development and production environments)

Comment: Also look into getting yourself an account on github (if you don't have one already) as it fits very nicely into any development cycle, and is supported in Capistrano. You could also create an account on heroku if you want a free place to host your app, great for easy public testing. Finally if you have time to learn it, you can't go wrong with vim for development (though TextMate is great).